# How are Constructors different from normal methods in Java?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I read the following in a Spring tutorial talking about Aspects.

> Unlike constructors in most other OOP languages, Java constructors are different from normal methods.

Is that true? If yes, why and how? I understand the difference and importance of Constructors vs. Normal methods. But, is that difference in C++ same as that in Java? Or, is there any other tweak to this difference in Java?

**My point of view is focused on the comparison with other OOP languages like C++.**

Say **A** is the explanation for the difference between Constructors and Normal methods in Java. Say **B** is the explanation for the difference between Constructors and Normal methods in any other OOP language. I want to know **the difference between A and B, if any?**

Comment: can you post the link where you read this, it might be having some context to answer your question.

Comment: My point of view is focused on the comparison with other OOP languages like C++.

Comment: in each and every OOP language in the world *constructors are different from normal methods.*

Comment: I read it in the book on Spring in Action 4th Edition by Craig Walls.

Comment: I understand the difference and importance of Constructors vs. Normal methods. But, is that difference in C++ same as that in Java? Or, is there any other tweak to this difference in Java?

Comment: @PankajDwivedi : see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865800/c-vs-java-constructors

Comment: Say A is the explanation for the difference between Constructors and Normal methods in Java. Say B is the explanation for the difference between Constructors and Normal methods in any other OOP language. I want to know the difference between A and B, if any?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I cannot add anymore ideas into the question. It is unfortunate that nobody is willing to read through the question more patiently.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor will have exact same name as the class and it does not have any return type at all, not even void. Constructors can be very useful for setting initial values for certain member variables.

Constructors and methods differ in three aspects of the signature: modifiers, return type, and name. Like methods, constructors can have any of the access modifiers: public, protected, private, or none (often called package or friendly). Unlike methods, constructors can take only access modifiers. Therefore, constructors cannot be abstract, final, native, static, or synchronized.

The return types are very different too. Methods can have any valid return type, or no return type, in which case the return type is given as void. Constructors have no return type, not even void.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this instruction:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
```

The first part `new Foo();` is an operation combining an operator (`new`) and an operand (`Foo()`). Behind the scenes, this allocate memory in the heap with the size of the `Foo` **class**, eventually fill it by calling what we call the *constructor* and returns a reference to this newly created object.

The second part `Foo a =` declares a variable of type `Foo` that memorize the reference given from the part above.

Now that we have a reference to an instance of `Foo` we can call some methods of this object. For example:

```
a.makeNoise();
```

A method can't be called with the `new` operator (syntaxically incorrect) and doesn't allocate some memory on the heap but instead execute a list of instructions.

In conclusion, constructors are different from methods because they can't be used in the same situations and don't do the same work behind the scenes.